# jsTree fails on second refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using a jsTree plugin and found that on the second time I call the refresh(), the tree will remain in an error / loading state.
Here is the code:

```
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var i, j, selectedNode;
    selectedNode = data.node;
    currentlySelectedNodeGUID = selectedNode.id;
    //for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
    //    selectedNode = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]);
    //    currentlySelectedNodeGUID = selectedNode.id;
    //}
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LocationProperties","Location")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: currentlySelectedNodeGUID },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#locationPropertiesPartial').html(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
});
```

The only problem I found was that I get this error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
at this line `currentlySelectedNodeGUID = selectedNode.id;`.

The data however is there, the `data.node` does contain an id property and it does have a value, which gets assigned to `currentlySelectedNodeGUID`.

I'm pretty much clueless as to why this happens. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `refresh()` your currently selected node is deselected, which triggers the `changed` event. When there is no node selected `data.node` is `null` (or `undefined`). That's why `data.node.id` also is `undefined`. After the tree has been refreshed the node gets selected again, which triggers `changed` once again - this time with the node object available.

So you'll need to check if there actually is a node selected before you send that ajax query.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate whether `data.node` or `data.selected` is null before the assignment,
when the jstree is refreshed don't take error, and you can refresh any times you need.

```
if (data.node != null) {
   var dataid = data.node.id;
}
```